# Is there a Blockchain StackOverflow? As in an alternative to stack overflow which is blockchain-based

Tags: blockchain

***Is there a Blockchain StackOverflow.com alternative?***

I'm wondering if there exists some product, which is basically just stackoverflow but a blockchain platform? Something which cannot be controlled centrally, where perhaps answers are rewarded with some *coin*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be. (And there are probably existing alternatives to the one I mention below... )

[DelegateCall](https://medium.com/loom-network/announcing-delegatecall-com-the-first-dappchain-live-on-loom-network-f95912388a4c), which was run by Loom Network (of CryptoZombies fame). It was based on its own DPOS chain, bridged to Ethereum via a relay.

*"DelegateCall is a Q&A site for Blockchain and Ethereum-related questions that runs fully on a Loom DAppChain."*

It was around for a couple of years I believe. The issues in the early days were lack of moderation, and therefore very low quality posts, to the point where you'd have to dig around to find something useful. (In my opinion... )

It now seems to have silently disappeared...

Comment: Hmm needs proper execution. With a focus on what SO does not do: Get guaranteed speedy answers. One could imaging a mix between Chegg.com and SO, with Crypto components being the means of payment rather than subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

[www.Helix.im](http://www.Helix.im) is trying to do that now. Basically, partnering with Web3 companies to recruit their existing community members for moderations, and rewarding them for their participation

Answer (score 0):

[Peeranha](https://peeranha.io/) claims to be a decentralised "Decentralized website with questions and answers that rewards users with crypto tokens for their contributions." However it is unclear how much of it is decentralised at the moment.

Comment: They look like scam